# Can't understand why the wincounter doesn't increase if we input the same letter "ch" every time

Tags: c

[This is where I have taken the code from](https://rextester.com/TIL55476)Why is this program working right even if I enter the same letter "ch".Shouldn't the wincounter increase every time, I guess the correct letter. So if I keep guessing the same letter, it should increase wincounter to original word's length without guessing the other letters. for example, if in "andrea", if I keep guessing a, it should declare me a winner. But the program works completely fine, what's the reason. Why the wincounter remains same for a single guessed character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
     char word[20];         //Used to store the user word. Most words are 
     less than 20 characters so the default size is 20.
     char stars[20];            //A string full of * that are replaced upon 
     the user entering the right letter of the word.
     int counter = 0;           //A counter to use in the for loops.
     int len;               //len is the length of the word entered.
     char ch;               //ch is a temporary character variable.
     int strikes=0;         //strikes counts how many wrong characters the 
     user has guessed.
     int trigger = 0;           //The trigger variable serves as a flag in 
     the for loops bellow.
     int wincounter=0;          //wincounter keeps track of the number of 
     correct guesses.
     int i;             //Another counter variable to be used in for loops.
     printf("\n\nEnter a word:");           //Ask the user to enter a word.
     scanf("%s", &word);
     len = strlen(word);                    //Make len equal to the length 
     of the word.
     //Fill the stars string with * according to the input word length (len)
      for(counter=0; counter<len; counter++)
      {
          stars[counter]='*';
      }


      stars[len]='\0';                  //Insert the terminating string 
      character at the end of the stars string.


      //Enter main program loop where guessing and checking happens. 26 is 
      //for 20 maximum characters + 6 strike characters.
      for(counter = 0; counter<26; counter++)
      {

          if(wincounter==len)                   //If the number of correct 
          //guesses matches the length of the word it means that the user 
          //won.
          {
              printf("\n\nThe word was: %s\n", word);
              printf("\nYou win!\n");
              break;
          }

          if(strikes==6)                        //If the user makes 6 wrong 
          guesses it means that he lost.
          {
              printf("\n\nThe word was: %s\n", word);
              printf("\n\nYou lose.\n");
              break;
          }

             printf("\n\n\n\n%s", stars);   //Print the stars string 

             printf("\n\nGuess a letter:");  //Have the user guess a letter.

             scanf(" %c",&ch);

             for(i=0; i<len; i++)  //Run through the string checking the 
                                   //characters.
             {
                 if(word[i]==ch)
                 {
                     stars[i]=ch;                   //If the guess is 
                                 // correct, replace it in the stars string.
                     trigger++;             //If a character the user 
                   //entered matches one of the initial word, change the 
                  //trigger to a non zero value.
                     wincounter++;                  //Increase the number of 
                  //correct guesses.
                 }
             }

             if(trigger==0)
             {
                 strikes++;                     //If the trigger is not a 
             //non zero value, increase the strikes counter because that 
             //means 
             //that the user input character didn't match any character of  
              //word.
             }

             trigger = 0;                       //Set the trigger to 0 again 
             //so the user can guess a new character.
      }

      printf("\nPress any key to exit.");
      while (!kbhit()){};                       //Wait for user to hit a 
      //key. This is done to keep results on-screen and not close the 
      //terminal/cmd window right away.
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, guessing `a` constantly declares me as winner.

Comment: After the third letter **a** it tells me "You win!" That's because it matches two letters 3 times, and 6 is the length of the string. If you overwrite each letter found with say a space or a star this won't happen.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &word);`  in C, a 'bare' reference to an array degrades to the address of the first character in the array.  prepending a `&` to the array name results in a type: `char (*)[20]` which is not valid.  Suggest: `scanf("%s", word);` And since this statement can result in undefined behavior, suggest adding a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the array..  I.E. `scanf("%19s", word);`  and should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%19s", word) != 1 ) { handle error and exit }`

Comment: OT: regarding: `len = strlen(word);`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`  such an 'automatic' conversion from a `long unsigned int` to an `int` can result in a corrupted value

Comment: "kbhit in C language. kbhit() is present in conio.h and used to determine if a key has been pressed or not. To use kbhit function in your program you should include the header file “conio.h”. If a key has been pressed then it returns a non zero value otherwise returns zero."  Note that the header file `conio.h` is not included and that header file is non-standard.  Strongly suggest replacing:  `while (!kbhit()){}; ` with `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF ){;} getchar();`  amongst other things, this eliminates the CPU hogging loop and is very portable